# find('count') keep getting total no. of rows instead of the value 0

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

Why do I keep getting the total no. of rows instead of the value 0 when i've entered "" - empty ?

Controller

```
$totalSchools = $this->Classroom->find('count', array('conditions' => array('Classroom.name LIKE' => '%'. $searchQuery .'%')));
$this->set('totalSchools', $totalSchools);
```

View

```
<?php echo $totalSchools ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should filter first your `$searchQuery` if it is empty like here:

```
if($searchQuery != ""){

      $totalSchools = $this->Classroom->find('count', array('conditions' => array('Classroom.name LIKE' => '%'. $searchQuery .'%')));
       $this->set('totalSchools', $totalSchools);

}
    else
        $this->set('totalSchools', 0);
```

Comment: because if the `$searchQuery` is empty, you ended up getting everything in your table as in like `count(*)`

Answer (score 1):

Because an empty string evaluates to '%%' => this matches **everything**. You have to check for this special case with an if/else.